# NoScript for Safari

Tags: software-recommendation, safari, security, plugins, privacy

I find myself drifting away from Firefox to Safari, but the lack of NoScript is making me a little uneasy. Is there an equivalent plugin for Safari?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's also [JavaScript Blocker](http://jsblocker.toggleable.com).

Comment: "Automatic rules make it easy to block any script that isn't from the same domain of the webpage you're viewing." That sounds great. Not even NoScript can do that (I think). For example, I want to allow twitter's js, but only when on twitter.com, and not embedded on other sites.

Comment: Wow, this is a really nice implementation of a script blocking extension. It's only sad that you cannot block scripts that are within a page itself. This is "a limitation of the Safari extension design".

Comment: @gentmatt's comment from 2012 is out of date, this plugin does block inline scripts now.

Comment: This script makes my Safari slow. Often opening gmail is a nightmare. Apart from that, it is superb.

Comment: This no longer works at all with Safari 12+.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not super familiar with NoScript, but from a quick glance at the site, I can think of two good starting points - how useful they are will depend on which features of NoScript you make use of.

[ClickToPlugin](http://hoyois.github.com/safariextensions/clicktoplugin/) is a great plugin blocker, pretty configurable, and it also has a fantastic h.264 replacement for Flash video. It substitutes h.264 video with a nice tidy player (mostly just the standard Safari player with one or two modifications) wherever it can, probably gets 80-90% of video in my experience. Makes in-browser video a lot nicer.

[JavaScript Blacklist](http://homepage.mac.com/drewthaler/jsblacklist/) blocks 3rd party JS stuff, good for stuff like tynt.com and all those double-underlined shopping popup links in forums. Configuration options may be a bit basic for your tastes, but it's a good start.

Comment: JavaScript Blacklist no longer exists (nor indeed does anything on `homepage.mac.com`

Answer (score 2):

[Ghostery](http://www.ghostery.com) is a great option if you're just aiming for privacy. It runs in every browser on every operating system, even mobile ones.

Comment: Ghostery is not recommended due to closed source and tracking: https://gitlab.com/prism-break/prism-break/issues/1225